# What exactly does "frame_locked" mean?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, guys.
I am trying to study rivz using this [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz).

I saw a message,  "frame_locked", parameter of the Marker header.
I found the description for understanding on this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker).
But I can not understand what does it mean.

> frame_locked [1.1+]
> Tells rviz to retransform the marker into the current location of the specified frame every update cycle.

What exactly does "frame_locked" mean?
When can I use it? How it work on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/290293/what-exactly-does-%22frame_locked%22-mean?/) by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2018-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without the frame_locked parameter the marker object will be placed into the RVIZ view with the transform at the time it was produced. The location of the marker in RVIZ is then set and will not change in the future even If the TF tree changes.

However if you set the frame locked parameter, future changes to the TF tree will effect the location of the marker. This means changes to the TF tree will be reflected in the markers position in real time.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [harderthan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34798/harderthan/) on 2018-05-14**:
Thank you. It helped me.